# Print general tree levels

Tags: c++, tree, levels

Sorry for my bad english.

I need to print the levels of a general tree or n-ary tree.

The struct of the tree is:

```
struct GTnode{
    int data;
    nodeGT *fc; //first child
    nodeGT *nb; //next brother
}
```

The difficulty of the algorithm is when you have 2 different node in the same level and each one have a child.

*Editing*
If I have this tree for example:

```
              1
     2        7        8
  3    6            9     12
 4 5              10 11
```

I have to print:

```
1
2 7 8
3 6 9 12
4 5 10 11
```

Each *endl* represents a different level in the tree

*Editing*
An idea of my code is the next:

```
void printLevel(GTnode *root){
   GTnode *aux = root;
   if(root != NULL){
      cout<<aux->data;
      printLevel(aux->nb);
      cout<<end; //Print the space between levels
      printLevel(aux->fc);
   }
}
```

I know this is wrong but is just an idea of what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a level-order/breadth-first traversal of the tree ([wp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)). To do that you need a queue. Put the root in the queue. Then do this until the queue is empty: Take the first out, add its ->fc to the queue and go to its ->nb (go through all the ->nb's until there are nomore and each time you add its ->fc to the queue).